# Lining up text with proportional fonts

Tags: fonts, align

Suppose I want to show text data in two columns like here:

[image]

As you can see the font in the columns is proportional (not monospace).

How can text data be shown in an emacs buffer like this, with the first characters in the two columns lining up nicely like on the picture? With proportional font.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I haven't yet used the space display property, so this didn't occur to me.

Comment: @Drew post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Done............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Elisp manual, node [Specified Space](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Specified-Space.html):

> To display a space of specified width and/or height, use a display
>   specification of the form `(space . PROPS)`, where `PROPS` is a property
>   list (a list of alternating properties and values).  You can put this
>   property on one or more consecutive characters; *a space of the specified
>   height and width is displayed in place of **all** of those characters*.

For example, use a `display` spec that includes `(space :align-to 30)`.